# Vugen Runtime Settings are incomplete

Tags: performance, loadrunner, vugen

Why, in my LoadRunner, when I want to configure runtime settings my options are only this :

[image]

But I want to change Internet Procotol & normally my options should be like this :

[image]

Do you know why ? My LoadRunner version is 12.50.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Web Services protocol.
[image: LoadRunner - Web Service Protocol]

You can create a new script and choose Web-HTTP protocol, then you will see thinktime option.
[image: LoadRunner - Create a new script]